# filling color to only some part of svg icon using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, svg

hi i want to fill the color to the custom shape with animation based on percentage  value.
example:if i give percntage value is 50,it raises to 50 percent like the following shape.

i am doing this task by reffering following link.

but it doesnt work when iam using another svg icon.
my html code is

```
<div class="icon">
    <div id='blackIcon' class="icon-doubleheart">
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/yourcareassets/doubleheart.svg"/>
    </div>
    <div id='holdci'>
        <div id='colorIcon' class="icon-doubleheart">
            <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
```

Comment: i am using refer link is http://jsfiddle.net/4uza82nr/

Comment: Show what you have tried.  In code terms.